# Caret's SVM behaving strangely

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to create a toy 2D dataset on which to visualize the performance of the SVM algorithm. I produced a dataset which is perfectly separable:

```
n <- 200;

d<-data.frame(x=runif(n), y=runif(n))

d$class[-1 + 3 * d$x < d$y] <- "1"
d$class[-1 + 3 * d$x > d$y] <- "2"
```

However, I don't understand the warnings I get when I run the line:

```
library(caret)

train(class~., data=d, method='svmLinear', tuneGrid=data.frame(C=1))
```

The method returns a lot of warnings, all of the type:

```
  23: In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 3,4,10,12,14,16,18,22,24,27,30,34,35,38,39,45,47,52,54,56,57,64,67,72,74,76,78,81,83,84,87,88,91,92,94,99,103,108,109,111,113,115,117,118,120,121,123,128,129,131,135,137,138,140,141,143,145,146,148,153,164,171,173,178,181,187,189,191,193,194,198 --> row.names NOT used
```

Furthermore,

Can anyone explain what in the world is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your model and works fine. You can ignore the warning.

This issue was filed under [issue 410](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/410) on the github page of caret. This is now resolved and will be fixed when a new version is available on cran (version higher than 6.0-70). Or you can download a new version from github.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure about what is causing the warnings. But when I used other approach to fit model using train function as below:

```
train(x=d[, c("x", "y")], y=factor(d$class), method='svmLinear', tuneGrid=data.frame(C=1)
```

I did not get any warnings. The performance of both the methods, is very much same.